# Where does linux store my syslog?

Tags: c, linux, logging

I wrote a simple test application to log something in a log file. I am using **linux mint** and after the application executes I try to view the log using this command:

```
tail -n 100 /var/log/messages
```

but the file messages does not exist neither tested or something. Below you can find my code. Maybe I am doing something wrong, the file isn't stored there or I need to enable logging in linux mint.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <syslog.h>

void init_log()
{
    setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_NOTICE));
    openlog("testd",LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL1);
}

int main(void) {

    init_log();
    printf("Session started!");
    syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "Session started!!");
    closelog();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: It depends on the system logger you are using. It should have a configure file somewhere in `/etc/` that you have to change for your identifier (`"test"` in your case) and facility.

Comment: It seems SuSE SLES 15 SP4 no longer installs rsyslog by default.  Apparently, no matter what I pass into `setlogmask()` or `openlog()`, all syslog() messages appear on the console / `stdout`.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

On my Ubuntu machine, I can see the output at `/var/log/syslog`.

On a RHEL/CentOS machine, the output is found in `/var/log/messages`.

This is controlled by the `rsyslog` service, so if this is disabled for some reason you may need to start it with `systemctl start rsyslog`.

As noted by others, your `syslog()` output would be logged by the `/var/log/syslog` file.
You can see system, user, and other logs at `/var/log`.

For more details: here's an [interesting link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-log-files-location-and-how-do-i-view-logs-files/).

Comment: See this also:  
http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch05_:_Troubleshooting_Linux_with_syslog#.Uy_0VvmSwep

Comment: It doesn't seem that `/var/log/syslog` is any kind of true default; perhaps Ubuntu configures that itself.

Comment: perfect! the `systemctl restart rsyslog` worked.
previosly I wasnt able to access my logs, and now i know the why, Thanks! <3

Answer (score 25):

Default log location (rhel) are

General messages:

```
/var/log/messages
```

Authentication messages:

```
/var/log/secure
```

Mail events:

```
/var/log/maillog
```

Check your `/etc/syslog.conf` or `/etc/syslog-ng.conf` (it depends on which of syslog facility you have installed)

Example:

```
$ cat /etc/syslog.conf
# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none         /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                             /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                 /var/log/maillog

#For a start, use this simplified approach.
*.*                                     /var/log/messages
```

Answer (score 23):

In addition to the accepted answer, it is useful to know the following ...

Each of those functions should have *manual pages* associated with them.

If you run `man -k syslog` (a keyword search of man pages) you will get a list of man pages that refer to, or are about **syslog**

```
$ man -k syslog
logger (1)           - a shell command interface to the syslog(3) system l...
rsyslog.conf (5)     - rsyslogd(8) configuration file
rsyslogd (8)         - reliable and extended syslogd
syslog (2)           - read and/or clear kernel message ring buffer; set c...
syslog (3)           - send messages to the system logger
vsyslog (3)          - send messages to the system logger
```

You need to understand the manual sections in order to delve further.

Here's an excerpt from the man page for man, that explains man page sections :

```
The table below shows the section numbers of the manual followed  by
the types of pages they contain.

   1   Executable programs or shell commands
   2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
   3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
   4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
   5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
   6   Games
   7   Miscellaneous  (including  macro  packages and conven‐
       tions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
   8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
   9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

To read the above run

```
$man man
```

So, if you run `man 3 syslog` you get a full manual page for the `syslog` function that you called in your code.

```
SYSLOG(3)                Linux Programmer's Manual                SYSLOG(3)

NAME
   closelog,  openlog,  syslog,  vsyslog  - send messages to the system
   logger

SYNOPSIS
   #include <syslog.h>

   void openlog(const char *ident, int option, int facility);
   void syslog(int priority, const char *format, ...);
   void closelog(void);

   #include <stdarg.h>

   void vsyslog(int priority, const char *format, va_list ap);
```

Not a direct answer but hopefully you will find this useful.

Comment: sh: man: command not found

Comment: This won't help the user to figure out which file syslog writes to. `man 5 syslog.conf` would indirectly tell how to figure this out, but again doesn't actually state what the default files are on a given system.

Answer (score 9):

You have to tell the system what information to log and where to put the info. Logging is configured in the `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file, then restart rsyslog to load the new config. The default logging rules are usually in a `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` file.

Answer (score 5):

syslog() generates a log message, which will be distributed by syslogd.

The file to configure syslogd is /etc/syslog.conf.
This file will tell your where the messages are logged.

How to change options in this file ?
Here you go
http://www.bo.infn.it/alice/alice-doc/mll-doc/duix/admgde/node74.html

Comment: What if my /etc/syslog.conf only contains comments? Is there a default location where the logs go?

Comment: Link is broken...

Answer (score 5):

Logging is very configurable in Linux, and you might want to look into your `/etc/syslog.conf` (or perhaps under `/etc/rsyslog.d/`). Details depend upon the logging subsystem, and the distribution.

Look also into files under `/var/log/` (and perhaps run `dmesg` for kernel logs).

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Ubuntu under WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux) and `systemctl start rsyslog` didn't work for me.

So what I did is this:

```
$ service rsyslog start
```

Now `syslog` file will appear at `/var/log/`

Answer (score 1):

Something very important that people had not mention, in order to identify how is working the logging application on ur OS is checking the configuration file.

Based on the logging applications on linux history, these are the available ones:

- syslog :  `/etc/syslog.conf` (first version)
- rsyslog : `/etc/rsyslog.conf` or `/etc/rsyslog.d/` (current version that most of the distribution uses)

Checking the configuration files, ure gonna figure out how logging is working on ur system ( and where are located the files ).

Finally, to check what's the system unit or deamon that handles logging, you can check that with the following command:

```bash
systemctl list-unit-files *syslog*
systemctl status rsyslog
```

Greetings,