# syslog() messages written to a file

Tags: linux, file, syslog

I'm new to using syslog() on linux, but I really like the format and functionality of it. I'm trying to figure out whether or not I can generate a file that saves all the syslog() messages so that I can go back and review them later. Is that possible?

Comment: Are they not already stored? (/var/log/)

Comment: It may be because I'm running uClinux on Smartfusion2 board, but there's nothing in /var/log/ :(

Answer (score 0):

`syslog()` automatically logs to a file. Start by checking `/var/log/syslog`.

The location of file will vary depending on your linux distribution and the type of message you log (the first argument to `syslog()`).

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10979435/7954580) for more details.

Comment: So, I'm actually running uClinux on a SmartFusion2, and when I screen into it, I'm not able to find anything in the var/log/ directory. The syslog on my computer is there but doesn't have any of the logs I'm generating from the code on the SmartFusion2.